# JAVA. Reading from file, returning BigInteger value

Tags: java

I ran into a problem. I have a code which should read a BigInteger from a file and run Collatz hypothesis test. The problem is, that I want to make a method to return the value to the main code. However, this code doesn't return a value. If I put print statement into the while loop, it works. However, as I try to return the value or put a print statement outside of the while loop it doesn't compile. What might be the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
public static BigInteger readFile() {
    File file = new File ("C:\\number.txt");
    try {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            BigInteger n = scan.nextBigInteger();
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return n;   
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile? You should declare 'n' outside of your try...catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace it with:

```
public static BigInteger readFile() {
    File file = new File ("C:\\number.txt");
    BigInteger n = null;
    try {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            n = scan.nextBigInteger();
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return n;   
}
```

Comment: This actually worked! But it's still not so clear to me. Why couldn't I just put BigInteger to the loop? Why it had to be placed before the try/catch?